# ActionScript 3.0 reading from text file and assign content to a string

Tags: string, actionscript-3, flash, text

I have a problem while reading content of a text file and write it into a string. I always have 1 word in text file and I want to assign that word to a string. Here is what I could(n't) do up to now:

```
function lastGameFile()
{
file = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("LastGame.txt");

var docDir:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory;

var fileString:String = docDir.nativePath;

var lastgameLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
lastgameLoader.load(new URLRequest(file.url));
lastgameLoaderXML();
lastgameLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,lastgameLoaderXML);
lastgameLoader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR,IO_ERROR_lastgameLoaderXML);                  
    }

function IO_ERROR_lastgameLoaderXML(e:Event):void
{
    trace("IO_ERROR_lastgameLoaderXML")
}                       
function lastgameLoaderXML()
{
    trace("lastgame loader dan atıyor")
    lastgameXML = new XML(file);
    lastGameName = lastgameXML.GameName;
    FileName = lastGameName;
}
```

LastGame.txt is my text file and I want to assigh content to FileName.

Comment: Are you using AIR or Flex for web ?

Comment: I'm using AIR. Question is my codes are not working, how can i make them working

Comment: Why isn't your code working? Do you get errors? What kind of errors? At what line does the error occur? Does your method get called? Does `FileName` get assigned? What value does `FileName` get? You really have to be more clear when asking a question if you want others to help you out.

Comment: Sorry, I just wanted to know if my codes are correct or not. I'm always getting errot for lastgameLoader and it directs to IO_ERROR_lastgameLoaderXML part. However your answer worked fine and I'll mark it as correct. You're right about .load part. Thanks for answer.

Comment: Good to see it solved. Good luck!

Comment: thanks :) also following codes are working too. if someone else cannot use your corrections i suggest these ones:

const ISO_CS : String = "iso-8859-1";
  file = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("LastGame.txt");
  var fileStream:FileStream = new FileStream(); 
  fileStream.open(file, FileMode.READ);
  FileName = fileStream.readMultiByte( fileStream.bytesAvailable, ISO_CS);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try moving the eventlistener above the `.load` function. My guess is the event gets completed before you tell your application to run a function when the event is completed.

Also, you call your `lastgameLoaderXML()` twice, why is that?

Try this for the function `lastGameFile()`:

```
function lastGameFile()
{
    file = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("LastGame.txt");
    var docDir:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory;
    var fileString:String = docDir.nativePath;
    var lastgameLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
    lastgameLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,lastgameLoaderXML);
    lastgameLoader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR,IO_ERROR_lastgameLoaderXML);   
    lastgameLoader.load(new URLRequest(file.url));
}
```

And place `trace(preloader.response[0]);` somewhere in `lastgameLoaderXML()`.